# ASP.NET Web API and Authorization

Tags: asp.net-web-api

So I have an existing Windows Phone 7 app that uses my own authorization (player logs in with an alias and password and it verifies it against a db) going to an MVC web services.

Now I'm looking to move over to ASP.NET Web API and I'm a little confused as to how to add security for it?

I see there is the `AuthorizeAttribute`, but what do I need to do to allow them to be authorized?

Any guidance here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute` is only checking against `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to see if the user authorized to access the specified resource (in this case it is controller action) or not. It doesn't provide any type of authentication mechanism.

In your case, as you have username and password in place, you can do basic authentication. Best place to do this is inside a Message Handler. Here is an example: [BasicAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle/blob/master/src/apps/WebAPIDoodle.Http/Handlers/BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs)

I don't encourage you to use this as it is because there is no test behind this implementation but this should give you an idea. That class is an abstract class and when you set this as you base class for a message handler, you need to override the `AuthenticateUser` method and return `IPrincipal`. If the return value is null, that means user is not authenticated. If you provide an `IPrincipal`, that `IPrincipal` will be set and your `AuthorizeAttribute` can check against it.

You can, for instance, use [GenericPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.genericprincipal) class to create an `IPrincipal`. Assuming you are on ASP.NET host, you can register your authentication handler as below:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyAuthHandler());
```

To sum it up, do the authentication through a Message Handler somehow, no matter what type of authentication you use (Basic Auth, OAuth, etc.). And then, do the authorization through `AuthorizeAttribute`.

> Also, Dominick Baier has a nice presentation on [Securing ASP.NET Web
>   APIs](http://vimeo.com/43603474) and I recommend you to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you: [Custom AuthorizeAttribute for Web API controllers](http://freecodebase.com/Home/Article?articleId=1)